# Opening a new GUI window on a main GUI using GUI builder on netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, menuitem, menubar

I am playing about with GUI builder and i was wondering if there is an easy way to open the register window through the current main window (in reference to the page below). I am trying to do this through the menu bar.

I've been trying all day, because GUI Builder generates some code, its not possible to edit this code.

[image]

Thanks For the help!

Comment: In case ther is any confusion on the matter.. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: no one is blaming the IDE i was just making a point.

Comment: but thanks for the link and improvements suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on that shortcut button, click Events, click ActionPreformed.
There you should write codes to make your register window appear.
An example:

```
  private void RegisterationEventActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    JFrame Register = new Register();
    Register.setVisible(true);
  }
```

Remember to make another JFrame called ("Register" assuming u are using the code i gave) at the same package as your current JFrame
Maybe u would probably should use the run button (The button with a Green Triangle or Arrow), run it try to press the menu item, it should appear the register window.

Comment: Oh, you can always right click the same thing, choose Customize Code.

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate class which extends `JDialog` class and add your GUI components:

```
public Register extends JDialog {
   //Make GUI
   setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL); //Make it modal
}
```

Add `ActionListener` to that menu item which is supposed to open a register window:

```
mnuItmRegisteration.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Register r = new Register();
        r.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. And, oh...get rid of that GUI builder if you want to learn swing.

Comment: Thanks, but i only use GUI builder because its so easy to position things like buttons and text fields, its really hard to do this from scratch.  :)

Comment: @Marcello No its not! I used to create GUI apps with NetBeans GUI builder...until I realized I have no clue about Java swing. Also..have a look at that question from Andrews comment, because you are going to create a very unfriendly UI.

Comment: Okie dokie, i shall take this challenge.